# How to refer to the absolute row number in a \DTLforeach loop

Tags: conditionals, datatool

Consider the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

\DTLnewdb{table}

\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{hallo}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{non}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{bonjour}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{non}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{czesc}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{oui}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{hola}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{oui}

\section{display table}

\DTLdisplaydb{table}

\section{Subtable}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & row-number \\
\DTLforeach[\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}]{table}{\a=a,\b=b}{%
\a    &    \b & \arabic{DTLrowi}  \\
}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `\DTLforeach` loop runs on all rows for with the test `[\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}]` is true, i.e. all rows with `a=oui` or rows 3 and 4. The command `\arabic{DTLrowi}` delivers the row number of the current row in the loop, but it refers to the "subtable" generated by the restriction `[\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}]`. In this subtable, they are rows 1 and 2.

My question: I want to refer to the original row numbers (3 and 4 in this case). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<condition>` associated with `\DTLforeach[<condition>]{..}{..}{<body>}` should then be used within `<body>`. Furthermore, the result of `\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}` returns `true` or `false` and should then be used in an `\ifthenelse{<condition>}{<true>}{<false>}` boolean clause:

```
\DTLforeach
  %[\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}]
  {table}
  {\a=a,\b=b}{%
    \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\b}{oui}}
      {\a    &    \b & \arabic{DTLrowi}  \\}
      {}%
  }%
```

This definition in your MWE produces:

[image]

Comment: simple and efficient :) I'm nevertheless puzzled, that the original rownumber is not anymore available in the DTLloop with the [test]

Comment: @nicolasroy: It is, but it is only stepped (incremented) when the `<condition>` is true. That's why migration to the body means it the default condition always holds (which is `true`), stepping the counter at *every* row, resulting in the correct output.